# SQL Server: is it possible to create a computed column that evaluates an aggregate?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable
ADD isNewest AS (
    CASE WHEN date in (select MAX(date) from SomeTable group by SomeGroup) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
) PERSISTED
```

is something like this possible?

I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

(This is trivially simplified. The application is a bit different, but the same question applies.)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

check this.

Comment: you can create a scalar function for the `select MAX(date) from SomeTable group by SomeGroup` and use that

Comment: oh, duh! sounds obvious now. Thanks @GabyakaG.Petrioli!

Comment: A view will probably work for you.

Comment: keep in mind this though: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance.aspx

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, the idea would be to persist it to increase performance (there aren't many writes / deletes to it, but are lots of reads). I think maybe a trigger will be a better solution though... you can't persist non-deterministic functions, turns out.